# STL bitset shift operator causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault, bitset

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  const int N = 1e9;
  bitset<N> st;
  st << 999;
  cout << st.test(0);
}
```

(Notice that operator `<<` is used, not `<<=`. And what I need is `<<`. Also don't remove the `cout` line, because then there will be no SegFault. I believe it's because of compiler optimizations).

This causes a segmentation fault on my machine. However after changing 999 to 1 no exception is thrown. What is the problem and what type of exception is thrown, And how can one solve it?

Another strange thing is that the code works on some computers, including ideone servers. But, not mine:

```
gcc version 9.2.1 20191008 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2)
```

So please explain why is the problem not reproducible on some computers?

Comment: This is probably a stack overflow. one option would be to make it `static`

Comment: @M.M `static bitset<N> st;` didn't do the job. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. if you are still having trouble, post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @M.M Did making static prevent segfault on your machine? Please don't remove the `cout` line because compiler tries to optimize the code and prevents segfault.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/6z3lWa)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Strange. In addition to my PC, quera.ir judging server gives me runtime error verdict.

Comment: [This also works for me](https://ideone.com/QQbOSf)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Operator `<<=` doesn't throw exception for me either. But does it work on your machine too, or just ideone servers?

Answer (score 3):

The original code most likely causes a stack overflow: the bitset might use hundreds of megabytes of memory whereas systems typically default to a stack size of a few megabytes.

The behaviour of exceeding the stack limit can vary between systems; in some cases it might appear to work as intended whereas in others there might be some kind of signal or crash or unpredictable behaviour.

You can fix the storage for the bitset by using `static bitset<N> st;`, or dynamic allocation. But then there is another issue. The statement:

```
st << 999;
```

calls an [overloaded operator function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_ltltgtgt) that returns a temporary bitset by value , so this temporary bitset will still cause the stack overflow.

To avoid this, you will have to not call `st << 999`.  You haven't said what you were trying to do with this code, but if you intend to modify the bitset in-place you can write `st <<= 999;`.  If you intend to make an altered copy without changing the original bitset , then first make a copy (using static or dynamic allocation) and then call `<<= 999` on the copy.

Comment: That is a good point about the possibility of hundreds of megabytes  being put on the stack, I completely missed that. And apparently there are numerous questions on StackOverflow about large bitsets crashing.